# How to get details of metrics at GCP Redis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

I have created a managed Redis at GCP. from GCP console I can view metrics like connected clients/ blocked clients; memory usage/max memory, etc.

How can I get these metrics results using gcloud CLI? Furthermore, how can I get more details of each connection like <client_ip:port> the Redis connects to, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you but check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-redis)

To see each connection Redis connects to, I believe it's not possible from gcloud, only using unix programs like netstat inside VM.